# Getting 404 Error while open PDF using href reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

{searchRecord.title}}
                        secondaryText={
                          
                            {stripHtml(searchRecord.highlightedText)}
                          
                        }
                      />
                    }

Comment: <ListItem
                        primaryText={<a style={styles.searchTitle}
                          href={`${HELP_FILE_PATH}/${relativePath}`}
                          type={'application/pdf'}>{searchRecord.title}</a>}
                        secondaryText={
                          <span
                            style={styles.description}
                          >
                            {stripHtml(searchRecord.highlightedText)}
                          </span>
                        }
                      />
                    }

Comment: Same location HTML files are able to open

Comment: Please add your markup into your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50854618/edit) it.